# Bulk delete discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, discord, discord.js

I've been building my discord bot and have run into some trouble!
my bulk delete works but only for the cmd that you type any more than that I get this error

```js
(node:146828) DeprecationWarning: Collection#find: pass a function instead
    (node:146828) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: args is not defined
        at purge (C:\Users\nevbw\Desktop\games\FBIBot\bot.js:29:13)
        at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\nevbw\Desktop\games\FBIBot\bot.js:46:2)
        at Client.emit (events.js:224:7)
        at MessageCreateHandler.handle
```

```js
client.on('message', message => {
        if (message.content === 'L!delete') { 
        async function purge() {
            message.delete();
                if (!message.member.roles.find("name", "LOLI POLICE")) { 
                message.channel.send('You need the \`LOLI POLICE\` role to use this command.');
                return;}
               if (isNaN(args[0])) {
               message.channel.send('Please use a number as your arguments. \n Usage: ' + `L!` + 'purge 
               <amount>');
            return;
            }
            const fetched = await message.channel.fetchMessages({limit: args[0]})
            console.log(fetched.size + ' messages found, deleting...'); 
            // Deleting the messages
            message.channel.bulkDelete(fetched)
                .catch(error => message.channel.send(`Error: ${error}`)); 
         it into the channel.
        }
        purge(); // Make sure this is inside the if(msg.startsWith)
        }
         });
```

Comment: the ``` is the code below is the actual cmd put in

Comment: You can't delete more than 100 messages at once or messages other than 14 days

Comment: @CedarBlocks it cant even delete two messages

Answer (score 0):

The error is caused by the way you're using `find()`, you need to pass a function into it

```js
if (!message.member.roles.find((role) => role.name === "LOLI POLICE"))
```

Comment: hi i've tried this and it comes up with the following error?
`C:\Users\nevbw\Desktop\games\FBIBot\bot.js:36
                const fetched = await message.channel.fetchMessages({limit: args[0]}); // This grabs the last number(args) of messages in the channel.
                                ^^^^^`

Comment: so its saying the await part

Comment: Srry for the late response but that was the full error the rest of it was just the bot files

Comment: that's not an error, that just points to the line causing the error, please edit the full error into your question.

Comment: (node:623324) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: args is not defined

Comment: yeah that's not related to my answer, how did you define `args`?

Comment: I guess it’s either `async function purge() {‘ or`if (isNaN(args[0])) {`